# Add values to List<Map<String, String>>

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a problem with my java code that I hope someone can help me with.

I need help adding values to a list of type `List<Map<String, String>>`.

I try with `myList.add(map.put(value1, value2))`, but that's wrong.

```
List<Map<String, String>> myList = null;
Map<String, String> map = null;

for (int i=0; i<daysList.getLenght(); i++)
{
    myList.add(map.put(value1, value2));  //This line is not working
}
```

Comment: You should initialize your List and Map and properly use AbstractMap.SimpleEntry or suchlike instead of Map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Map#put](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)) method doesn't return the map, it returns the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key.

If you want to add the map to the list, you'll need to do something like this:

```
map.put(value1, value2);
myList.add(map);
```

Comment: Thank you! I accepted your answer since you were the first one to give me the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the code as below

```
for (int i=0; i<daysList.getLength(); i++){
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put(value1, value2);
    myList.add(map);  
}
```

Method `put()` from Map.java returns

> the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key, if the implementation supports null values.)

**Your List needs Map object** but you are providing the previous value associated with the key which is not of type Map.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that way.
Try someting like that

```
List<Map<String, String>> myList = null;
Map<String, String> map = null;

for (int i=0; i<daysList.getLenght(); i++)
{

    map.put(value1, value2) //map is null so this line will throw NullPointerException
    myList.add(map);  //Also mylist is null if you fix map null problem another NullPointerException is thrown here
}
```

Comment: *"another NullPointerException is thrown"* ... well, not really ;P, since there was already an exception, so the method will be exited there.

Comment: @Tom Everyone know that I mean to "After fixing first line, second problem will come from here". I have edited and tried to explain that on answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of a class that implements the `Map` interface (e.g., a `HashMap<>`) to place in the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < daysList.getLenght(); i++) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(value1, value2)
    myList.add(map);
}
```